# Apache Camel Forwarding and Order of Messages

Tags: apache-camel

I am investigating to see if the following requirement can be met by Camel. The requirement is: the order of the messages on the incoming queue should match the order of the messages on the outgoing queue.

I think the question boils down to the internals of how Camel forwards the messages from the incoming queue to the outgoing queue.

In the simple example, where a route looks like this:

```
from("incomingQueue").to("outgoingQueue);
```

and incomingQueue has 4 messages to start with (arrived in this order): message 1, message 2, message 3, message 4.

Is there a guarantee or an option to tell Camel to forward the messages in a way which maintains the original order of receipt? So if a listener is listening on the outgoing queue, it will receive message 1, then message 2, then message 3 then message 4 (assuming a one thread receiver).

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if you have a single threaded consumer on the route, then it will move one message at a time between the queues in the order.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Claus. So Camel as a routing engine guarantees that moving messages between two endpoints (in my case queues) maintains the order of the messages between the source and the destination. Does Camel use a single thread to move messages between 2 endpoints? Is it configurable? Can you point me to a reference?

Answer (score 2):

A queue is first in first out. So by nature in a single threaded process, the queue #2 would receive the messages in the same order as queue #1. Most endpoints have a way to reduce the consumers to 1 if you want to.

If you want to keep your consumer count up, then you could maybe use a [resequencer](http://camel.apache.org/resequencer.html) before placing the messages on the queue #2. Just before the message is put on queue #1, you can populate a header with a sequence number, then the resequencer before queue #2 would ensure they are reordered

Comment: Thanks Dakota. I understand that queues are first in first out. My question is primarily on how Camel as a routing engine moves messages between endpoints/queues and whether the routing itself is single threaded or multi-threaded. All the options that I have seen relate to many endpoints like: parallelProcessing (send messages in parallel to many endpoints). I didn't see a parallelProcessing option for sending messages from one endpoint to another endpoint (excluding something like splitter EIP).

Comment: As far as I understand, routes are by default single threaded (due to consumer endpoint configuration). Even components with thread pools are defaulted to 1 concurrent consumer. if you are using a JMS component (like the activeMQ one above), you can override this by setting the concurrentConsumer parameter in the uri. It all depends on the endpoint you are using.